# General expression of a (maybe 3 or 2 dim) sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, logarithms, irrational-numbers, polylogarithm

$\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{1}{4}$    $\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{1}{6}$    $\frac{1}{4}$  $\frac{11}{24}$

$\frac{1}{8}$    $\frac{1}{6}$  $\frac{11}{48}$  $\frac{5}{12}$

$\frac{1}{10}$   $\frac{1}{8}$  $\frac{11}{72}$  $\frac{5}{24}$ $\frac{137}{360}$

$\frac{1}{12}$ $\frac{1}{10}$ $\frac{11}{96}$  $\frac{5}{36}$ $\frac{137}{720}$  $\frac{7}{20}$

$\frac{1}{14}$ $\frac{1}{12}$ $\frac{11}{120}$ $\frac{5}{48}$ $\frac{137}{1080}$ $\frac{7}{40}$ $\frac{363}{1120}$

...

Does anyone know what's the generate term expression for this number sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are $$\frac{|S_{m,2}|}{m!n}$$ where $S_{m,2}$ are the Stirling numbers of the first kind, $m$ is the column (starting from $m=2$), and $n$ is the row counting from the diagonal (i.e. row-col+1).

The Stirling numbers $|S_{m,k}|=\begin{bmatrix}m\\k\end{bmatrix}$ are defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).

For $k=2$, they are $0, 1, 3, 11, 50, 274, 1764$, etc. So starting with $m=2$ and $n=1$, we get $$\begin{array}{l|lllll}
n=1&\frac{1}{2!}=\frac{1}{2}&\frac{3}{3!}=\frac{1}{2}& \frac{11}{4!}=\frac{11}{24}& \frac{50}{5!}=\frac{5}{12}& \frac{274}{6!}=\frac{137}{360}\\
n=2&\frac{1}{2!2}&\frac{3}{3!2}& \frac{11}{4!2}& \frac{50}{5!2}& \frac{274}{6!2}\\
n=3&\frac{1}{2!3}&\frac{3}{3!3}& \frac{11}{4!3}& \frac{50}{5!3}& \frac{274}{6!3}
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I took a look at wiki I don't quite see how this rows and columns work. Would you show which table of Stirling number you are using?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Further_example

Comment: @YUMU Modified the answer to explain more.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer!